# What is appropriate to include as a comment to an answer and what is not?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

I posted a comment to a SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32183286/896660) because the proposed solution did not work for me. Basically I think the answer is now stale and not working as advertised.

The user who had provided the answer is now telling me that my comment is not appropriate, and I should ask a new question if I want help. But my question would be exactly the same as the OP's question, so it would surely be marked as a duplicate. What are the comments to answers for if they are not to comment on the correctness of an answer?

Comment: It is indeed *very* inappropriate.  Just because the user answered a *similar* question does not in any way obligate him to listen to your problem.  You have a different error message, it therefore needs to be a different question.  Google the message first, then if still necessary click the Ask Question button.

Comment: In my opinion, in that circumstance you were right to make that comment, because it was totally inherent to the question asked above (and to be precise it was not so much your question but rather an extension of the question). 
But as you see I can't do anything because as long as my reputation doesn't grow. . . At most I can only give you my consent as I am doing! :D **good luck**

Comment: To clarify: I don't have a "different error message". I have the same error message as the OP, but when I tried the solution proposed in the answer, I got an error message.

Answer (score 4):

Your comment indicates that you're in a different situation than the person asking the question, as you're having a problem that they weren't having.  The response that you got is entirely appropriate; since you have having a different problem, you should ask a separate question that distinguishes itself by explaining what problems you are having implementing that solution that the others didn't have. (Assuming you do your research on your new problem, and are unable to find a suitable solution.)

Comment: How so? I believe I have the exact same problem as the OP. I tried the solution proposed, and it does not work. So I am commenting that the solution does not work. Solutions go stale because third-party software libraries change. If I see a comment that a proposed solution is not working for someone else, that is very helpful information.

Comment: @robguinness You have the same end goal as another user, yes.  But you're not both starting in the same spot.  They asked a question about why they were not able to do something, and a solution was provided based on situation they were in.  You are in a different situation, and while your end goal is the same, the actual problem you're having is different, and as a result, the question you need to have answered is different.  In this case, someone else already had a distribution and needed to activate it, my (non-expert) reading suggests that you don't have it at all.  Different problems.

Comment: Why are you assuming I am in a different situation?

Comment: @robguinness Even if it is "the same problem" exactly, you _do_ have a different question- You can open your own. Just be sure to outline that you tried the answers to the linked question, and what you got when you tried them. _That_ is what will keep your question from being a duplicate. Clearly, those answers won't answer your question. (Those answers not working _is exactly_ what makes it a new question.)

Comment: How is my question different? I haven't even asked a question! I am claiming I have the exact same question as the OP, but others are claiming I have a different question.

Comment: @robguinness The most significant factor for me is because the solution that worked for the other user isn't working for you.  Next would be that the answerer seems to feel that you are in a different situation, hence their comment, and I certainly trust their judgement more than mine (as I'm not a python dev), and least significantly, my interpretation of the problem, as described in my last comment, reads as two different situations.

Comment: @robguinness How is your question the same?  Your question is why you get an error saying you don't have a valid version of the distribution when trying to install python.  The question that you linked to was someone trying to use a python feature (not realizing it wasn't it installed and activated).  Completely different questions.

Comment: @robguinness As I said in the last line of my comment, _those answers not working for you is exactly what makes it a new question._ You have the same _base_ question, however the current answers do not work for you. _Outline this when you ask your question_ and your question will not be a duplicate.

Comment: "The most significant factor for me is because the solution that worked for the other user isn't working for you." Why do you assume it worked for the other user? Also, what works at one point in time doesn't necessary work at a later point in time. Software ecosystems change. Commenting on an answer is one way to flag that a solution is no longer the correct one.

Comment: @robguinness I guess I just assumed that "you can't install this software because you don't have it" isn't really a thing that changes over time, and that it's an error that you're going to get anytime you try to install something that yo don't have the distribution for.  Apparently the answer author didn't think so either, based on their comment.

Comment: Let's start again. The question was: "How to run ipython from venv?" The answer provides a solution to install a package, which includes a specific command. This no longer works because that package no longer exists. I made a comment to this effect, but I was told I should not make a comment, I should ask a new question. My question is still, "How to run ipython from venv?" I try the proposed solution to Q. It does not work because the package has changed. To me the answer should be modified, not a new Q asked. My comment flags that the solution no longer works for ANYONE who has the same Q.

Comment: Found this: "...we're doing everything possible to make sure that the useful content that is created when a question asked becomes available and easily accessible to everyone else in the entire world, instead of forcing (or encouraging) every single person that has the same problem to ask a new question." - @Servy

Comment: @robguinness But you *don't* have the same problem.  You have a radically different problem.  That you have a completely different problem in attempting to accomplish the same broad goals doesn't mean you have the same question.  That question is asking about trying to accomplish that *when python isn't activated*, whereas you're trying to solve that problem *when you don't even have the distribution*.  Those are two different problems, with two different solutions.

Comment: If I have a different problem than the OP, why does the answer propose installing the package?

Comment: @robguinness Because that's the solution to their problem.  But it's not the solution to your problem, because you have a different problem.

Comment: I have to say I really don't understand you. I'm sorry.